# Existence of convex function in manifolds of non-negative curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, convex-analysis, riemannian-geometry

In the paper,

*Cheeger, Jeff; Gromoll, Detlef*, [**On the structure of complete manifolds of nonnegative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970819), Ann. Math. (2) 96, 413-443 (1972). [ZBL0246.53049](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0246.53049), it has been proved that any complete manifolds $M$ of non-negative curvature can be covered with compact, totally convex and totally geodesic submanifolds $\{C_t\}$ such that for $t_2\geq t_1$ implies $C_{t_1}\subset C_{t_2}$. 
Let $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous convex function then $f$ is constant on each $\{C_t\}$ and hence $f$ is constant on $M$. 
But I know this is not true since there are continuous convex function on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I can not find where I am doing wrong. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: Where did the sentence "Let $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous convex function then $f$ is constant on each $\{C_t\}$ and hence $f$ is constant on $M$" come from?

Comment: In the paper "Non-existence of continuous convex functions on certain Riemannian manifolds" by S T Yau proved that there does not exists any nontrivial continuous convex function in complete manifold with finite volume. So according to this theorem $f$ is constant on each $\{C_t\}$.

Comment: Who says that this manifold has finite volume? (It does not.)

Comment: Since each $\{C_t\}$ is compact so $f$ is constant on each $\{C_t\}$. Let $f$ is not constant in $M$ so $f(x)=a$ and $f(y)=b$. Hence there exists $r$ and $s$ such that $x\in C_r$ and $y\in C_s$. Take $t_0=max\{r,s\}$ then $x,y\in C_{t_0}$. So $a=b$. Hence $f$ is constant in $M$.

Comment: Since you did not understand my question, let me ask again: Why do you think $M$ has finite volume?

Comment: But I have not assumed that $M$ has finite volume

Comment: The mistake is the assumption that the restriction of a convex function to $C_t$ is still convex: Consider a linear function on $R^2$ restricted to a circle.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To close this question: It stems from the confusion between  two notions: Of a manifold and a manifold with boundary. The subsets $C_t$ in Cheeger-Gromoll are submanifolds with boundary (except maybe for one of them, the "soul" of $M$). On the other hand, Yau's theorem (which in the case of compact manifolds is just the  trivial observation that a convex nonconstant function on a connected Riemannian manifold cannot attain local maxima) is about manifolds without boundary. Hence, it does not apply to $C_t$. Of course, $\partial C_t$ has no boundary but then restriction a convex function to $\partial C_t$ is no longer convex (in general).